# How do you merge two javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js

I have one object like this

```
let ob1 = {
'item_data':{
  'stack':{
    'purchase':'12345',
    'order':'22222'
   }
  }
}
```

and another object like this

```
let ob2 = {
  'stack':{
    'purchase':'444444'
   }
 }
```

The resultant object should look like this

```
result = {
  'item_data':{
    'stack':{
      'purchase':'444444',
      'order':'22222'
     }
   }
 }
```

The code is in a nodejs application. I am wondering if there is any javascript library to do this kind of merge/replace objects in server side js.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: have you tried to write code to do this?

Comment: Have a look at Object.assign

Comment: I tried this `let d = Object.assign(ob1['item_data'], ob2 );` and it produce this result `{ stack: { purchase: '444444' } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few npm packages out there to accomplish this, but one that is very popular is `lodash.merge`.

Take a look at the lodash merge function:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge

> This method is like _.assign except that it recursively merges own and
>   inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into
>   the destination object. Source properties that resolve to undefined
>   are skipped if a destination value exists. Array and plain object
>   properties are merged recursively. Other objects and value types are
>   overridden by assignment. Source objects are applied from left to
>   right. Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous
>   sources.

And an example:

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};
var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Use the `lodash.merge` npm package to pull in just this method:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge

Good luck!

Comment: An additional note about `Object.assign`: It will only copy the top level property values over, so it won't by default do the "deep merge" illustrated in the question. We would need to create a recursive function to iterate and `Object.assign` each property in order for it to work. Leaning on others code like `lodash.merge` is going to be more convenient and less prone to corner case errors since its well used.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```
let ob1 = {
'item_data':{
  'stack':{
    'purchase':'12345',
    'order':'22222'
   }
  }
}
// and another object like this

let ob2 = {
  'stack':{
    'purchase':'444444'
   }
 }
Object.assign(ob1.item_data.stack, ob2.stack);
console.log(ob1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function merge(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
        if (exports.merge.call(b, key) && b[key]) {
            if ('object' === typeof (b[key])) {
                if ('undefined' === typeof (a[key])) a[key] = {};
                exports.merge(a[key], b[key]);
            } else {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
merge(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: Why to use so complex function if that can be done by one line `Object.assign` .

Comment: found this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge and seems working . Thank you everyone for prompt response.